# GitHub for Windows; disable ctrl + shift + alt + c

Tags: github, github-for-windows

When I press `ctrl + shift + alt + c` my browser opens a new tab, which is a new gist of what's currently in my clipboard. This only happens when GitHub for windows is running. How can I disable it!? I can't find any information about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a Feature, Not A Bug :)  It's a shortcut that GitHub for Windows registers to help you quickly create Gists to share with people.

Comment: It's very cute; but how do I disable or rebind it? I actually need that combo for something else. o:

Comment: At the moment, there is no way to disable it :-/  I thought it would be obscure enough that nobody would miss that keyboard shortcut, but there's a *few* people that do

Comment: That would be those of us who have mapped it to something specific in for instance visual studio because it's obscure enough to not be used by anything common. 
Should I raise a GhfW support request to un-map it / provide the option?